# Request assistance with a Pyspark scenario

Tags: pyspark

I have a file with the below format, and i need to parse it into a dataframe with seven columns. Can you please help me on how to proceed ? I am new to pyspark
This data has comma as well as pipe as delimiters.

1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy

2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy

3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance

4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my trial. I think the tags should be a column of array not for each column. But anyway, I tried.

```py
df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").csv("test.txt").toDF('id', 'title', 'tags')

df1 = df.withColumn('tags', f.split('tags', '\|'))
df1.show(truncate=False)

+---+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|id |title                   |tags                                             |
+---+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|1  |Toy Story (1995)        |[Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fantasy]|
|2  |Jumanji (1995)          |[Adventure, Children, Fantasy]                   |
|3  |Grumpier Old Men (1995) |[Comedy, Romance]                                |
|4  |Waiting to Exhale (1995)|[Comedy, Drama, Romance]                         |
+---+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+

df2 = df1
for i in range(0, 5):
    df2 = df2.withColumn('tag' + str(i), f.col('tags')[i])

df2.drop('tags').show(truncate=False)

+---+------------------------+---------+---------+--------+------+-------+
|id |title                   |tag0     |tag1     |tag2    |tag3  |tag4   |
+---+------------------------+---------+---------+--------+------+-------+
|1  |Toy Story (1995)        |Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy|
|2  |Jumanji (1995)          |Adventure|Children |Fantasy |null  |null   |
|3  |Grumpier Old Men (1995) |Comedy   |Romance  |null    |null  |null   |
|4  |Waiting to Exhale (1995)|Comedy   |Drama    |Romance |null  |null   |
+---+------------------------+---------+---------+--------+------+-------+
```